What pronoun should I use, "by we who" or "by us who"?

He will be yelled at by we who hate him.
He will be yelled at by us who hate him.

After by you use us, but in this case I'm confused. Which one of these sentences is correct?

The structure has no elegant solution.

Both the objective (after the preposition) and the subjective (for  we who hate him) are required. A solution (really an accepted fudge) is to use case-masking 'those' / 'the people' / 'all' / 'those of us'. But a complete rephrasing is arguably better: 'We hate him;/ and we will yell at him.'

@Lambie The original might (admittedly clumsily) equate 'we/us' and the haters, whereas 'those of us who hate him' is partitive. Then only the rewrite I give last (of those offered so far) is accurate.

The structure has a solution which is elegant and idiomatic: "by us". The "who" is correctly "who" because it is the subject of "hate". That is sufficient justification for "who"; no more is needed. In particular, the word "who" doesn't entail changing the "us" to "we".  This answer shows an analogous construction.
